# javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Can anyone told me how to solve this error in GAE with Google SQL Cloud
I've run with localhost is no problem but when I deploy to GAE it's show this error

> javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:619)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:616)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:390)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:368)
>       at net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService.processCall(PersistentRemoteService.java:205)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
>       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
>       at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
>       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:452)
>       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:458)
>       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:698)
>       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:336)
>       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:328)
>       at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:456)
>       at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

This code for Hibernate Util

```
package com.ies.ieschool.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
try {
// Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
} catch (Throwable ex) {
// Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
}
}

public static SessionFactory getSession() {
return sessionFactory;
}

}
```

This one for DTO

```
package com.ies.ieschool.shared;
// Generated 31 �.�. 2555, 1:54:03 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import net.sf.gilead.pojo.gwt.LightEntity;

/**
* Province generated by hbm2java
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "province", catalog = "ieschool")
public class Province extends LightEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private short provinceId;
private Geography geography;
private String provinceCode;
private String provinceName;
private Set<Father> fathers;
private Set<Mother> mothers;
private Set<Student> studentsForAddressProvince;
private Set<Student> studentsForAddressCensusProvince;
private Set<Student> studentsForGraduatedSchoolProvince;
private Set<Student> studentsForBirthAddressProvince;
private Set<City> cities;
private Set<ExperienceWork> experienceWorks;
private Set<District> districts;
private Set<Guardian> guardians;
private Set<Postcode> postcodes;
private Set<Personal> personalsForAddressProvince;
private Set<SeminarProfile> seminarProfiles;
private Set<Personal> personalsForLicenseIssueProvince;

public Province() {
}

@Id
@Column(name = "province_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public short getProvinceId() {
    return this.provinceId;
}

public void setProvinceId(short provinceId) {
    this.provinceId = provinceId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "geography_id", nullable = false)
public Geography getGeography() {
    return this.geography;
}

public void setGeography(Geography geography) {
    this.geography = geography;
}

@Column(name = "province_code", nullable = false, length = 2)
public String getProvinceCode() {
    return this.provinceCode;
}

public void setProvinceCode(String provinceCode) {
    this.provinceCode = provinceCode;
}

@Column(name = "province_name", nullable = false, length = 150)
public String getProvinceName() {
    return this.provinceName;
}

public void setProvinceName(String provinceName) {
    this.provinceName = provinceName;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "province")
public Set<Father> getFathers() {
    return this.fathers;
}

public void setFathers(Set<Father> fathers) {
    this.fathers = fathers;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "province")
public Set<Mother> getMothers() {
    return this.mothers;
}

public void setMothers(Set<Mother> mothers) {
    this.mothers = mothers;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "provinceByAddressProvince")
public Set<Student> getStudentsForAddressProvince() {
    return this.studentsForAddressProvince;
}

public void setStudentsForAddressProvince(Set<Student> studentsForAddressProvince)                                 {
    this.studentsForAddressProvince = studentsForAddressProvince;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "provinceByAddressCensusProvince")
public Set<Student> getStudentsForAddressCensusProvince() {
    return this.studentsForAddressCensusProvince;
}

public void setStudentsForAddressCensusProvince(
        Set<Student> studentsForAddressCensusProvince) {
    this.studentsForAddressCensusProvince = studentsForAddressCensusProvince;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "provinceByGraduatedSchoolProvince")
public Set<Student> getStudentsForGraduatedSchoolProvince() {
    return this.studentsForGraduatedSchoolProvince;
}

public void setStudentsForGraduatedSchoolProvince(
        Set<Student> studentsForGraduatedSchoolProvince) {
    this.studentsForGraduatedSchoolProvince = studentsForGraduatedSchoolProvince;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "provinceByBirthAddressProvince")
public Set<Student> getStudentsForBirthAddressProvince() {
    return this.studentsForBirthAddressProvince;
}

public void setStudentsForBirthAddressProvince(
        Set<Student> studentsForBirthAddressProvince) {
    this.studentsForBirthAddressProvince = studentsForBirthAddressProvince;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "province")
public Set<City> getCities() {
    return this.cities;
}

public void setCities(Set<City> cities) {
    this.cities = cities;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "province")
public Set<ExperienceWork> getExperienceWorks() {
    return this.experienceWorks;
}

public void setExperienceWorks(Set<ExperienceWork> experienceWorks) {
    this.experienceWorks = experienceWorks;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "province")
public Set<District> getDistricts() {
    return this.districts;
}

public void setDistricts(Set<District> districts) {
    this.districts = districts;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "province")
public Set<Guardian> getGuardians() {
    return this.guardians;
}

public void setGuardians(Set<Guardian> guardians) {
    this.guardians = guardians;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "province")
public Set<Postcode> getPostcodes() {
    return this.postcodes;
}

public void setPostcodes(Set<Postcode> postcodes) {
    this.postcodes = postcodes;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "provinceByAddressProvince")
public Set<Personal> getPersonalsForAddressProvince() {
    return this.personalsForAddressProvince;
}

public void setPersonalsForAddressProvince(Set<Personal> personalsForAddressProvince) {
    this.personalsForAddressProvince = personalsForAddressProvince;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "province")
public Set<SeminarProfile> getSeminarProfiles() {
    return this.seminarProfiles;
}

public void setSeminarProfiles(Set<SeminarProfile> seminarProfiles) {
    this.seminarProfiles = seminarProfiles;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "provinceByLicenseIssueProvince")
public Set<Personal> getPersonalsForLicenseIssueProvince() {
    return this.personalsForLicenseIssueProvince;
}

public void setPersonalsForLicenseIssueProvince(
        Set<Personal> personalsForLicenseIssueProvince) {
    this.personalsForLicenseIssueProvince = personalsForLicenseIssueProvince;
}
}
```

This one for DAO

```
package com.ies.ieschool.server;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import com.ies.ieschool.client.service.ProvinceService;
import com.ies.ieschool.shared.Province;
import net.sf.gilead.core.PersistentBeanManager;
import net.sf.gilead.core.hibernate.HibernateUtil;
import net.sf.gilead.core.serialization.GwtProxySerialization;
import net.sf.gilead.core.store.stateless.StatelessProxyStore;
import net.sf.gilead.gwt.PersistentRemoteService;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ProvinceImpl extends PersistentRemoteService implements  ProvinceService{

public ProvinceImpl() {
    HibernateUtil hibernateUtil = new HibernateUtil();    
                      hibernateUtil.setSessionFactory(com.ies.ieschool.util.HibernateUtil.getSession());

    PersistentBeanManager persistentBeanManager = new PersistentBeanManager();   
    persistentBeanManager.setPersistenceUtil(hibernateUtil); 
    StatelessProxyStore sps = new StatelessProxyStore();
    sps.setProxySerializer(new GwtProxySerialization());
    persistentBeanManager.setProxyStore(sps);

    setBeanManager(persistentBeanManager);
}

@Override
public Province findProvinceByPK(int provinceId) throws Exception {

    Province province;
    Session session = com.ies.ieschool.util.HibernateUtil.getSession().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    province = (Province) session.createQuery("SELECT new Province( " +
            "pvn.provinceId, " +
            "pvn.provinceName " +
            ") " +
            "FROM Province pvn " +
            "WHERE pvn.provinceId = :id " +
            "ORDER BY pvn.provinceName").setInteger("id", provinceId).uniqueResult();   
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return province;
}

@Override
public List<Province> findAllProvince() throws Exception {

    List<Province> list = null;
    Session session = com.ies.ieschool.util.HibernateUtil.getSession().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    list = new ArrayList<Province> (session.createQuery("SELECT new Province( " +
            "pvn.provinceId, " +
            "pvn.provinceName " +
            ") " +
            "FROM Province pvn " +
            "ORDER BY pvn.provinceName").list());   
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return list;
}
}
```

This one for hibernate mapping (hibernate.cfg.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>        
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:google:rdbms://ies-thamvitya-db:ieschool/ieschool_rif</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</property>  
    <mapping class="com.ies.ieschool.shared.Province" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , RPC calls cannot run in some devices like IOS and Andriod. So you'd better avoid using RPC calls.

Try to use Ajax request to call your functions from the back. It goes well in all circumstance.